# How to use Ansibles wait_for module 'active_connection_states' param

Tags: ansible

Starting in Ansible v2.3 there is a new parameter for  [`wait_for` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/wait_for_module.html):  `active_connection_states` which default value is: `[u'ESTABLISHED', u'SYN_SENT', u'SYN_RECV', u'FIN_WAIT1', u'FIN_WAIT2', u'TIME_WAIT']`

Now imagine I want to wait for connections only with state in: 
`['ESTABLISHED', 'SYN_SENT', 'SYN_RECV']` to ensure load balanced connection have been drain after request it using any of the load balancers Ansible modules.

Example:

```
- wait_for:
    host: 0.0.0.0
    port: 8080
    state: drained
    active_connection_states: {{ connection_states_to_wait_for | default("[u'ESTABLISHED', u'SYN_SENT', u'SYN_RECV']") }}
```

Error:
`

`

Also tried `default("[u'ESTABLISHED', u'SYN_SENT', u'SYN_RECV']")` with same result.

Note I am trying to change module default behaviour but still using a variable to allow my plan or execution to wait for a different set of states, would be nice but not mandatory to use this ;)

How should I use this new param? I tried several approaches but none worked, and that's all I could found at the module documentation.

Comment: Something or someone ate the error message. But this is supposed to be a list not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter is supposed to be a list, not a string:

```
vars:
  connection_states_to_wait_for:
    - ESTABLISHED
    - SYN_SENT
    - SYN_RECV
```

And/or:

```
active_connection_states: "{{ connection_states_to_wait_for | default(['ESTABLISHED', 'SYN_SENT', 'SYN_RECV']) }}"
```

<sup>You also need to properly quote the parameter value, as it starts with `{` character.</sup>